# Returning object from C# COM method and memory ownership

Tags: c#, c++, .net, com

I have implemented a COM component in C#:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid("E052BB1C-7ADC-47F4-99E1-9407E2FA0AA2")]
public interface IColorRamps
{
    IColorRamp getColorRamp();
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("EE47F2F2-0AD9-437C-8815-D570EACF2C07")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("ColorRamps.ColorRamps")]
public class ColorRamps : IColorRamps
{
    public IColorRamp getColorRamp() { ... } 
}
```

I call this from C++:

```
IColorRampPtr colorRamp;
{
    ColorRamps::IColorRampsPtr colorRamps(ColorRamps::CLSID_ColorRamps);
    HRESULT hr = colorRamps->getColorRamp(&colorRamp);
    colorRamp.AddRef(); // Should I do this??
 }
```

At first I did not have the AddRef() call and things seemed to work except I got strange crashes on "R6025 (pure virtual function call) run-time error" after running this code many times.

The signature in the autogenerated .tlh file is:

```
virtual HRESULT __stdcall getColorRamp(/*[out,retval]*/ struct IColorRamp * * pRetVal ) = 0;
```

When calling functions like this in C++ I am used to the function doing an AddRef() itself and passing on memory ownership to the caller. Is this not the case in C# COM?

I did NOT call Marshal.AddRef() inside ColorRamps.getColorRamp().

Answer (score 3):

That is most likely to happen because you `Release()` the pointer than because .NET forgot to `AddRef()` before returning (hint: .NET surely did not forget this).

`IColorRampPtr` is itself a smart pointer, you must be using it because you [`#import`ed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) the .NET generated type library in VC++.  As such, you should never call `Release()` on the smart pointers, as it'll be released when it goes out of scope (or, if used in a class member, when the object is destroyed).

If you want a raw pointer, on which you must later call `Release()`, use the raw interface pointer (e.g. `IColorRamp*`) or [`Detach()` the smart pointer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b.aspx).  Generally, you need a raw interface pointer when its scope becomes indeterminate.  If the scope is well defined and you can use a smart pointer, keep it as a smart pointer.

Comment: I am pretty sure I do not Release() the pointer. Since it is a smart pointer I assumed that it should take care of itself. The crash I encountered may come from some other place in the code, but the fact is that when I called AddRef() I could not reproduce it. I was thinking that the pure virtual function call exception may come from the Runtime Callable Wrapper?

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.addref%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) :

> The common language runtime manages the reference count of a COM
>   object for you, making it unnecessary to use this method directly. In
>   rare cases, such as testing a custom marshaler, you might find it
>   necessary to manipulate an object's lifetime manually. After calling
>   AddRef, you must decrement the reference count by using a method such
>   as Marshal.Release. Do not rely on the return value of AddRef, as it
>   can sometimes be unstable.

Worth a look?